# Why does Python Fabric replace underscores with hyphens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I'm trying to run this simple [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/getting-started.html#addendum-the-fab-command-line-tool) example and am getting an unexpected error.

```
# fabfile.py
from fabric import task

@task
def upload_and_unpack(c):
    if c.run('test -f /home/jones/test.yml', warn=True).failed:
        c.put('test.yml', '/home/jones')
```

```
$ fab -H 'web.example.com' upload_and_unpack
No idea what 'upload_and_unpack' is!
```

```
$ fab --list
Available tasks:

  upload-and-unpack
```

As can be seen, Fabric seems to have replaced the underscores in my method with hyphens.  Here are my versions:

```
$ fab --version
Fabric 2.4.0
Paramiko 2.4.2
Invoke 1.2.0
```

Why is Fabric doing this and how can I correct this error?  I see [here](http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#cli-arguments-options-and-behavior) a note about task names getting converted from underscores to hyphens but why show and example that defines the method with underscores if Fabric converts them to hyphens?  What is the right way to write and execute a method like this?

Comment: As for *"why"*: aesthetics. On the command line, hyphens are more common, but in Python, you can't name a function with hyphens. That's all. Use `fab ... upload-and-unpack` to invoke your function, done.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue.

In my case, it happened to be `click` 7.0
After I reverted `click` to 6.0, the underscores weren't replaced any more.